# Get the list from 2 relational tables and display

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have tables "Category & SubCategory". CategoryID is "foreign key" in SubCategory Table. I need to fetch all the Category and related SubCategories and bind in an Accordion list.

This is my code:

```html
<div id="accordian" data-bind="foreach:Categories">
     <div class="panel-heading">
         <h4 class="panel-title"><span data-bind="text: CategoryName"></span></h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
         <ul data-bind="foreach:SubCategories">
             <li><a href="#"><span data-bind="text: SubCategoryName" ></span></a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: I can fetch Category name and list it, but i am not able to get subcategories of that particular category and bind it.. as i am new to this i dont have idea, please help how to do it.

Comment: Well, then you should show how you get the categories.

Comment: Are `SubCategories` even part of your ViewModel? (we have no idea)

Comment: I agree with @Invent-Animate.  It might be helpful to see your view model that the html you've shown is binding to.  Also, are you able to get the subcategories from your database?  Can you insert a breakpoint or view source to see if the subcategories are there?

Comment: `var VM = function () {
    function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        });
    }
    self.Categories = ko.observableArray();
    function getCategories() {
        ajaxHelper(CategoryUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.Categories(data);
        });
    }
    getCategories();
}` This way i am getting categories..

Answer (score 0):

I have created a demo with fake response which should be provide via you endpoint. There were also missing **self** declaration in order to have object reference. So simply add following in begging of you VM.

```
var self = this;
```

I have also created fake method which simulate fake data array the same as you service should to provide.

```
 function ajaxHelperFakeResponse(callback) {
      var response = [{
          CategoryName: 'catgeory1',
          SubCategories: [{
            SubCategoryName: 'SubCategoryName1'
          }, {
            SubCategoryName: 'SubCategoryName2'
          }]
        }];
      callback(response);
    }
```

You can see whole solution in my fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/jakethashi/ow785abr/